# Magento - Modify Form Enctype via Event Observers

Tags: forms, events, magento, observer-pattern

I'm trying to add extra attributes to CMS pages. I am able to add these extra fields by following the help at http://blog.flexishore.com/2011/08/add-custom-field-to-cms-page/.

However, I cannot add images as the form for CMS pages does not have the enctype="multipart/form-data". To get around this I am having to create a local copy of the original Magento file. \app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Cms\Page\Edit\Form.php

Ideally, I would like to inject the enctype using the observer. I have trolled around everywhere and haven't come across a suitable solution.

I was hoping to be able to add something like $form->setHtmlAttributes('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')

```
  public function prepareFormMainTab(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
    $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fieldset', array(
        'legend' => 'CMS Extras',
        'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
            )
    );

    $fieldset->addField('imagefile', 'image', array(
        'name' => 'imagefile',
        'label' => 'Image',
        'title' => 'Image'
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

First, I extended the Mage_Adminhtml and Mage_Cms modules. Somehow, the modification works even without doing this! Maybe someone could explain why.

```
  <modules>
    <Myname_Mymodule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Cms/>
        <Mage_Adminhtml/>
      </depends>
    </Myname_Mymodule>
  </modules>
```

I rewrite the Adminhtml block.

```
<blocks>
  <mymodule>
    <class>Myname_Mymodule_Block</class>
  </mymodule>
  <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
      <cms_page_edit_form>Myname_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Edit_Form</cms_page_edit_form>
    </rewrite>
  </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

I copied \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Cms\Page\Edit\Form.php to \app\code\local\Myname\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Cms\Page\Edit\Form.php and added the enctype for the form.

```
class Myname_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
  }

}
```

**NOTE**
Though I am able to get the desired result, I am unable to understand how.

1. I imagined that removing the "depends" bit from the module would stop the custom block from working. It didn't!
2. From what I read on various blogs, I should have had class Myname_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Form. Doing that doesn't work.

Comment: The "depends" bit ensures the listed modules load before yours does.  But core modules are always loaded first anyway, so you don't see a difference.  You only need to specify "depends" for 3rd part modules.

Answer (score 2):

```
</global>
    </events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <event_column_append>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>observer_class</class>
                    <method>addFormEnctype</method>
                </event_column_append>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer method should looks like:

```
public function addFormEnctype($observer){
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Class_Where_Form_Is_Instaniated){
        $form = $observer->getBlock()->getForm();
        $form->setData('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        //depends of form what you wand modify
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$form->setEnctype('multipart/form-data')
```

or

```
$form->setData('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I did try this before posting the question.

Comment: What does _$form->getUseContainer()_ outputs?

Comment: Set it to true and try again, but make sure that you've no wrapping form.

Comment: var_dump($form->getUseContainer());
var_dump($form->getUseContainer(TRUE));

Both of them return NULL

Comment: The problem is that there are no event observers for Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Form.